# How to plot a stacked area graph for grouped/categorized data in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

I have a dataset that is categorized on multiple fields. Example:

```
Time | CatA | CatB | CatC | Value
--------------------------------- 
1       A      X      P      4 
2       A      X      Q      6 
3       A      Y      R      3 
4       A      Y      P      7 
1       B      X      Q      8 
2       B      X      R      9 
3       B      Y      P      5 
1       A      X      Q      8 
2       A      X      R      2 
3       A      Y      P      6 
4       A      Y      Q      4 
5       A      Y      R      3
```

Now I want to plot a stacked area graph, such that for every time as an unit on X-axis I have corresponding data of Y as a combined attribute of the categories. E.g: (A,X,P) will have be one graph stack, (A,X,Q) will be another, (B,X,P) another and so on.

How do I plot this in R? (PS: I'm a novice to R)

Comment: Take a look at `ggplot2` package and the `geom_area` plot.

Answer (score 0):

Is the type of graph you are interested in?
Your data:

```
df<-read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Time  CatA  CatB  CatC  Value
               1       A      X      P      4 
               2       A      X      Q      6 
               3       A      Y      R      3 
               4       A      Y      P      7 
               1       B      X      Q      8 
               2       B      X      R      9 
               3       B      Y      P      5 
               1       A      X      Q      8 
               2       A      X      R      2 
               3       A      Y      P      6 
               4       A      Y      Q      4 
               5       A      Y      R      3")
```

Code to create the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
#combine all of the cat to a single label
df$cat<-paste(df$CatA, df$CatB, df$CatC)
ggplot(df, aes(x=cat, y=Value, fill=CatB)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#669933", "#FFCC66")) +
  xlab("Cat: A,B and C")
```